# Replace string "white-spaces" with "comma" and remove all but 5 first words

Tags: php, regex, string

Need a little help with string formatting...

I have a string like this:

`Bmw m3 fully equipped and low mileage`

I need to replace whitespaces with commas, and also at the same time remove all special characters (all non number non letter characters except swedish å ä ö)

Then I need to remove all but the first 5 words, or you could say everything behind the fifth comma sign.

I want something like this from the string above:

`Bmw,m3,fully,equipped,and`

Thanks

Comment: What if there are multiple consecutive whitespaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

([Result](http://www.ideone.com/ApX2y))

```
$res = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9åäö\s]/ui', '', $theString);
$arr = preg_split('/\s+/', $res, 6);
echo implode(',', array_slice($arr, 0, 5));
```

This assumes you want to join multiple consecutive spaces (e.g. `foo    bar`) together (`foo,bar`).

Answer (score 1):

mhmmm try this:

```
$string = "Bmw m3 fully equipped and low mileage";
$str = implode(',', explode(' ',$string,5));
echo substr($str,0,strpos($str, ' '));
```

not tested though....

Comment: Tested, works fine :) well, except for removing special characters, and it won't handle multiple whitespaces.